# CSS styling won't work on php function. (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

I can't get CSS styling to work on content returned from a wordpress php function:

```
<span id="featured-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
```

The CSS style will work for anything before or after the php for excerpt, but the excerpt itself refuses to be styled. The only way I seem to have any success is where I try to place the php inside the span tag, which hardly seems correct, and creates a new single-space blank line after the php ouput....

```
<span id="featured-excerpt" <?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've got code-wise, otherwise we're like blind men in a minefield!

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't yet figured out the code button - I've edited the post so that the code is now visible.

Comment: What is the intended output of `the_excerpt();` ? What are you expecting to be rendered/displayed? It's entirely valid to render php output between any style-based tag.

Comment: The php function call itself is useless here since your problem is on the client side. You need to post an example of what actually gets served, and the relevant css rules.

Comment: @ultranaut That's a fair point.

Comment: try `<?php echo the_excerpt();?>`

Comment: The intended output is that Wordpress will return an 'excerpt' consisting of the first few words of a post. Useful when posting links to posts.

Comment: you should also show us the code for your php function

Comment: Just tried adding 'echo' but it still does the same thing.

Comment: the code for the function is part of the base wordpress php code. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @nickhar sorry, I was directing that at the op, not your comment.

Comment: here is the CSS that I am trying to display - note I've simplified it in an attempt to isolate the problem: #featured-excerpt {
 border:blue dotted 3px;
}

Comment: @ultranaut - as a newbie I don't know exactly what you mean by 'what gets served'?

Comment: @nickhar - by saying that its valid to render php between style-based tags, do you mean inside them (as per my second piece above) or do you mean in between the two span tags, per the first example?

Comment: @mk_89 No, it displays an excerpt of a post, but I'm beginning to think this isn't a rendering issue, more a post selection issue.

Comment: @mk_89 maybe I'm being dense here, but his problem as stated is that his css rules aren't getting applied as he's expecting, so what would the code for the php function itself matter here? Not trying to be a dick, I'm just asking...

Comment: @ultranaut It's quite possible.

Comment: @platplaas Between/enclosed by, not _within_ unless the function is to do something other than display an excerpt. See the answer I gave and check the link if you haven't already.

Comment: @platplaas I mean, what is it that is actually on your page if you open it up in the browser and do view source.

Comment: @ultranaut - OK thanks for this - when inspecting the element inside a browser I see that the text returned by the php function is returned inside paragraph tags, which is evidently what is throwing my css out of whack.

Comment: Per the advice given above, I inspected the web page inside a web browser and discovered that the text returned by Wordpress' php excerpt function is returned inside paragraph html tags.

This means that the CSS for my span tags was being over-ridden. I've modified the CSS to target the p tags inside the relevant id selector and the problem is now solved.

Many thanks to the prompt feedback above which resolved this, as it had been driving me nuts for many days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which case... Just looked at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

It's entirely valid to:

```
<span id="featured-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
```

or

```
<div id="featured-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
```

**EDIT (and given the comments):**

Try removing the php function and render text, that way we'll know if this is a style or function issue:

```
<span id="featured-excerpt">Lord help us!</span>
```

How does it display? Does it display in your HTML output?

Comment: yes - the 'lord help us' does display correctly per the intended CSS styling. Per comments in above thread - I discovered that the wordpress php function for excerpt returned the text in paragraph tags. I've modified my CSS to include paragraph tags as a child, and now it works as intended: #featured-excerpt p { border:blue dotted 3px; }

Comment: On a side note, what I find remarkable is that Wordpress don't mention inherited/included tags/styling anywhere in the codex description for the function. Poor show Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

the_excerpt functions is returned with paragraph tags. The best easy solution is call the_content function instead of the_excerpt

the_content provide all css you add in content box.